# Pig - comparing two similar statement : one working, the other not

Tags: apache-pig

I begin to be really annoyed with PIG :the language seems really not stable, the documentation is poor, there are not that many examples on internet, and any small change in the code can give radical differences  :from failure to expected result.... Here is another kind of this last theme :

```
grunt> describe actions_by_unite;
actions_by_unite: {
    group: chararray,
    nb_actions_by_unite_and_action: {
        (
            unite: chararray,
            lib_type_action: chararray,
            double
        )
    }
}

-- works :
z = foreach actions_by_unite {      
generate group, SUM(nb_actions_by_unite_and_action.$2);};


-- doesn't work :
z = foreach actions_by_unite {      
x = SUM(nb_actions_by_unite_and_action.$2);
generate group, x;};

-- error : 
2015-05-08 14:43:44,712 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 107, column 16> Invalid scalar projection: x : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar
Details at logfile: /private/tmp/pig-err.log
```

And so :

```
-- doesn't work neither:
z = foreach actions_by_unite {      x = SUM(nb_actions_by_unite_and_action.$2);
                                    generate group, x.$0;};
--error :
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (AC,EMAIL,1.1186133550060547E-4), 2nd :(AC,VISITE,6.25755280560356E-4)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.ReadScalars.exec(ReadScalars.java:120)
```

Does anyone would know why ?
Do you have some nice blog / ressources to propose with examples to master this language ?
I have the o'reilly book, but it seems a bit old, I have the 'Agile Data Science' and the "Hadoop definitive guide" book with some examples in it... I found this page really interesting : https://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/apache-pig-group-by-nested-foreach-join-example/

Any good video on coursera or other inputs ? Do you guys also have problems with this language ? or I am simply dumb ?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That thing in particular is not because of Pig being unstable, it's because what you are trying to do is correct in the first approach, but wrong in the others.

When you make a `group by`, you have for each group a bag that contains X tuples. Inside a nested foreach, you have one group with its bag for each iteration, which means that a `SUM` inside there will yield a scalar value: the sum of the bag you are currently working with. Apache Pig does not work with scalars, it works with relations, therefore you cannot assign a scalar value to an alias, which is exactly what you are doing in the second and third approach.

Therefore, the error comes from attempting something like:

```
A = foreach B {
    x = SUM(bag.$0);
}
```

However, if you want to emit for each of the groups a scalar, you can perfectly do this **as long as you never assign a scalar to an alias**. That is why it works perfectly if you do the sum at the end of the `foreach`, because you are returning for each of the groups a tuple with two values: the group and the sum.